# Is it possible to use 'HttpRuntime' in a NUnit project?

Tags: c#, selenium, unit-testing, nunit, httpruntime

I'm following a [guide](https://medium.com/@williamchislett/writing-to-google-sheets-api-using-net-and-a-services-account-91ee7e4a291) to write output data from Visual Studio into a google spreadsheet. I'm using a NUnit project type for test-automation purposes.

At the end of the guide there is a code block that I pasted inside my project:

```c#
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using System.IO;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using WikipediaTests.Foundation_Class;

namespace AutomationProjects
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass : TestFoundation
    {
        public class SpreadSheetConnector
        {
        //Codeblock from guide pasted here!
        }
        [Test]
        public void test1()
        {
         //Test case 1. Do XYZ...
        }
    }
}
```

In the code block included in the [guide](https://medium.com/@williamchislett/writing-to-google-sheets-api-using-net-and-a-services-account-91ee7e4a291) there is a section that reads the JSON credential file:

```C#
private void ConnectToGoogle()
{
    GoogleCredential credential;                
    using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.BinDirectory, "Export Project-03e8aa07234e.json"),
        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(_scopes);
    }

    //...
```

But I get an error for the 'HttpRuntime' saying: `Error CS0103 The name 'HttpRuntime' does not exist in the current context`

There is no suggestion from VS to add a new 'using' reference so I'm assuming that is not the problem.

So what could be the problem? To whole codeblock from the: [guide](https://medium.com/@williamchislett/writing-to-google-sheets-api-using-net-and-a-services-account-91ee7e4a291)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - yes.

Long answer - I believe you need to add the `System.Web` dll here. C# projects do not add all dependencies by default -- rather, they provide you with a list of potential references, and let the user pick and choose on an as-needed basis.

Under your project, find the `Dependencies` section. Right click, and click `Add Reference`. Under `Assemblies`, find `System.Web` and check the box next to it, then click OK.

Once you add that, then you will need to add `using System.Web` to the top of your file.

This guide may help too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019